# Mirror FTP changes to local code with VS-2015

Tags: tfs, version-control, ftp, local

I've managed to edit sites through ftp connection in Visual Studio 2015 Professional version. How would I go about having those saved changes I make in the ftp Connection be mirrored in my local file system in a version control type of way?

(I've tried opening the site and then right clicking to select team foundation version control, this does not work)

Comment: Have you added all the files that you want to version-controlled in TFS? Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files that you want to version-controlled have been added into TFS, you just need to create a workspace and map it with TFS. Then you can get all files from TFS.